# Initialized property CCArray is still NULL after new CCArray

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have in scene class property in private section like

```
private:
CCArray* objects;
```

and in `init` I initialize

```
objects = new CCArray();
```

but when I put breakpoint in line below objects is NULL and I don't know why. It crashes when I call `objects->count();`
Why I cannot initialize property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have tagged this post with cocos2d-x 3.0.
Array has changed in cocos2d-x-3.0.

Initialize :

```
cocos2d::Vector<cocos2d::Sprite *> _bullets;
```

Populate:

```
//   add a bullet
Sprite *bullet = Sprite::create("circle.png")
this->_bullets.pushBack(bullet);  //  retains bullet
```

Looping:

```
//  loop through bullets
for (auto bullet: this->_bullets)
{
    //  do something with bullet.
    //  no need to cast in this case
    if (bullet->getPositionX() > 160)
    {
        //  ...
    }
}
```

Erasing :

```
this->_bullets->removeObject(bullet);
```

You can read all about it here:
http://dev.bunnyhero.org/2014/01/cocos2d-x-30-beta-the-new-vector-class/

Comment: can we also iterate through menuitems array too ? if yes then can you please give me one example .